# how to deserialize an int from wire format from socket in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message that contains a header and a body. The header has a member called size (reflecting the size of the entire message, i.e header plus body). Since protobuf (AFAIK) does not provide message boundary, I use the size (first element of header and fixed size of 4 bytes) to know how much to slurp from the socket.

Assuming I have read (or recv(2)ed) 4 bytes from the socket, I now need to convert (decode) this to an int so I can instruct recv(2) to slurp that much more.

How do I convert / decode this wire format to an int in C++ land ?

I have tried ParseFromString() but this function is returning a boolean and the doc does not tell me much.

I will show what I think is relevant...lets see

```
message PsdAgentMsg { 
    message Header { 
       fixed32 theSize = 1; // size includes header and message 
       uint32 theInstanceId = 2; 
       Type theMsgType = 3; 
    } 
    Header theHeader = 1;
    oneof theMsg { 
       abc = 2; 
       def = 3; 
       ghi = 4; 
       klm = 5; 
       PsdAgentGPCMsg theGPCMsg = 6; 
    } 
} 
message PsdAgentGPCMsg { 
    int32 theCount = 1; 
} 
...few minutes later..

PsdAgentMsg *msg = new PsdAgentMsg();   // psd msg is header + body
...
rc = recv(sock, buf, 4, 0);     // I am simplifying some stuff
std::string sizeString = buf;
...
size_t payloadSize = msg->ParseFromString(sizeString);
```

I am finding that payloadSize = 0. which is a false being assigned to a size_t. So ParseFromString() does not seem to be the right way to decode the 4 bytes. Again, I need to decode the sizeString to an int. so I can say
recv(sock, buf, payloadSize,0)

Comment: What exactly is sent?  Is it a message with a single `int32` field?  What's the type of `payloadSize`?  This question needs a [mcve] to be answerable.

Comment: Sorry I tried to insert some litteral text , but couldn't figure it out. I tried a single back quote, triple back tick, html tags...to no avail

Comment: that was typo...I have added that to the original post

Comment: We need to know what the wire format for the size is. There are lots of possible choices and without knowing which choice was made, it's not possible to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded message fields use wire-type 2: length delimited.

That means that it's encoded like this:

`<varint tagAndType> <varint messageLength> <theSize> <theInstanceId> <theMsgType>`

Where a `varint` is a base-128 varint as defined in the [protobuf encoding specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints).

---

What this means is that `theSize` isn't at a fixed offset from the beginning of the message.  To make things easer, you could send the total size of the message before you send the message itself.  i.e. given a message like this:

```
message PsdAgentMsg { 
    message Header { 
       uint32 theInstanceId = 2; 
       Type theMsgType = 3; 
    }

    Header theHeader = 1;
    oneof theMsg { 
       int32 abc = 2;
       string def = 3;
       double ghi = 4;
       uint32 klm = 5;
       PsdAgentGPCMsg theGPCMsg = 6; 
    } 
}
```

You could send your data as something like this:

```
PsdAgentMsg msg;
fillOutMessageFields(msg);

std::string encoded_msg = msg.SerializeAsString();
uint32_t size = msg.size();

// First send the message size as a fixed-size integer
size = htonl(size);
send(sockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0);

// Then send the message itself
send(sockfd, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0);
```

Then you could read it back at the other end like this:

```
// Read the size
uint32_t size;
rc = recv(sockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0);
assert(rc == sizeof(size));  // Or proper error handling
size = ntohl(size);

// Read the actual message
std::string encoded_msg(size, '\0');
rc = recv(sockfd, &encoded_msg[0], size, 0);
assert(rc == size);  // Or proper error handling

// Parse the message
PsdAgentMsg msg;
msg.ParseFromString(encoded_msg);
```

Comment: > What this means is that theSize isn't at a fixed offset from the beginning of msg ....
concerns me, I was hoping it is.

Comment: Both the tag-and-type and length fields of an embedded message field are variable-length.  If all of the types contained in `Header` were fixed-size you could come up with a constant offset, but it would depend on the exact message definition.  But since `uint32` is a variable-length type (and I don't know what a `Type` is) that isn't the case.  Better to just send a separate fixed-length size header IMO.

Comment: Thanks...I really like to see if I can avoid two phone calls scenario (one phone call to say expect size and another phone call to say, here is the payload)... so lets go back to header modification approach. You asked what type is Type. Type is an enum, which seems to be a varint , but I can change that to fixed32. The other header field (ie the InstanceID) can certainly be a fixed32. Then you said "the offset could be assumed but depends on the message". Are you saying that even if I change the header to be all fixed32 elements, the "theSize" offset still depends on the message?